# How to make a displayed geoJson property a link to another property in a Leaflet popup

Tags: leaflet, geojson, popup, hyperlink

I have markers on my map created by geoJson data that represent restaurants, bars, etc.... Each marker has 2 properties; 1)Name - name of the site, bar restaurant, etc... 2)Link-a link to the establishment's website. Currently, I have added a popup that displays the Name. My goal is to make the name based on  into a hyperlink based on the link property that the user can click on and open corresponding the website. How could I best achieve this?

```
var layerGroup = L.geoJSON(data, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.Name +'<br>'+feature.properties.Link);
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

My best guess would be something like this: `layer.bindPopup("<a href='feature.properties.Link'>" + feature.properties.Name + "</a>")`

[image]

Comment: Your "best guess" looks fine to me and it seems to work for your goal. What is the specific problem you have with this solution?

Comment: The solution above (best guess) did not seem to work when I originally tested it.

Comment: And now it is working? If not, please edit the question with any specific errors/error messages you get in the map and/or the developer console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pay attention to your quotes.

```js
var layerGroup = L.geoJSON(data, {
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup("<a href='" + feature.properties.Link + "'>" + feature.properties.Name + "</a>")
  }
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Ah, that got it. It was a syntax issue. So the above solution does work correctly when the proper quotes are used.